# Setting style for Vaadin Menu Popup in one view without impacting other

Tags: vaadin7

I have an issue with styling of Vaadin Menu.I want to have different style of **menu popup** on different page.That means if set the style in one view, it **should not impact other menu-bar popups in other view**.Is there anyway I can achieve that? I can use dynamic CSS inject or JavaScript to achieve,but I want to know if there is any other way to achieve this using CSS and Vaadin API.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly easy to configure using [themes](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/themes/themes-overview.html) and adding a [custom style to your menu bar](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/components/components-menubar.html) (scroll to almost the end), eg `menu.addStyleName("red");`. The sample below is very basic but you'll get the idea.

CSS configuration in your theme:

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Sample code:

```java
public class MenuBarComponent extends VerticalLayout {
    public MenuBarComponent() {
        MenuBar menu = new MenuBar();

        // add the custom style
        menu.addStyleName("red");

        // A top-level menu item that opens a submenu
        MenuBar.MenuItem drinks = menu.addItem("Beverages", null, null);

        // Submenu item with a sub-submenu
        MenuBar.MenuItem hots = drinks.addItem("Hot", null, null);
        hots.addItem("Tea", null);
        hots.addItem("Coffee", null);

        // Another submenu item with a sub-submenu
        MenuBar.MenuItem colds = drinks.addItem("Cold", null, null);
        colds.addItem("Milk", null);
        colds.addItem("Weissbier", null);

        // Another top-level item
        MenuBar.MenuItem snacks = menu.addItem("Snacks", null, null);
        snacks.addItem("Weisswurst", null);
        snacks.addItem("Bratwurst", null);
        snacks.addItem("Currywurst", null);

        // Yet another top-level item
        MenuBar.MenuItem servs = menu.addItem("Services", null, null);
        servs.addItem("Car Service", null);

        addComponent(menu);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image: Sample]

---

**Update**

Styling the `v-menubar-popup` is tricky because that element is created each time a menu is popped-out, but no custom style is appended. Under the circumstances you could use the following workaround starting with the sample above:

1) Completely change the menu's primary style:

```java
menu.setPrimaryStyleName("custom-menubar");
```

2) In your theme create a new style using the [menu-bar mixin](https://vaadin.com/api/valo/#mixin-valo-menubar) and add a custom style for the popup as well:

```
@include valo-menubar("custom-menubar", false);

.custom-menubar-popup {
    background-color: red;
    height: 90%; // adjust as needed
}
```

3) It may not be perfect and you may have to tweak the height depending on the items each menu has, because it's no longer calculated automatically, but the result looks promising
[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But my issue is different. It was my mistake I didn't post my comments explaining the exact problem. 
I want to set a style to v-menubar-popup so that I can control the height of popup. I want the popup to be 100% height so that it can grow till bottom of browser.
But the problem is I 've not found a way to do that without impacting other places.

Comment: @SatyaranjanDas indeed, that's a different story. I've updated my reply with a possible workaround, see the bottom section.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.I'll try once and check in the browser.